# Why flutter doctor doesn't verify everything up correctly?

Tags: flutter

I follow the flutter documentation correctly. I'm done installing flutter SDK, put it at the correct path(c:\src\flutter[my flutter]), open the flutter_console.bat, locate at the command line cd c:/src/flutter, run flutter doctor, to see if there is anythin I need to do, I found one

And I get this error

Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       to set up Flutter, run the following command:
       git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

And run the following command cd c:/src/flutter> git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git base on what the flutter doctor says

After, I run flutter doctor again, and GET THE SAME ERROR.
Am I wrong?

I have the command prompt and powershell 5.1, my system requirements fits the criteria on running flutter apps.

I expect I don't have any issue running flutter doctor again

Comment: have installed git in your system?

Comment: Sorry actually solved it. It is bug or something, I try to restart my computer and It work as expected. Thanks!

Comment: I already solved it on GitHub [issues #19359](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19359#issuecomment-518125343)

Comment: It was already been solved. make sure the path has no space:

For example: (has space)
C://sdk/has space/sdk

For example: (has no space)
C://sdk/hasnospace/sdk

execute flutter doctor in powershell(not in cmd)

You will see the different result now.

Make sure to follow the documentation correctly about the environment variable path.

Then execute flutter doctor in powershell.

I fixed mine by accessing sdk without space, fix environment variable, restart computer, and by executing flutter syntax in powershell. SOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you got the wrong path of the SDK. 
Maybe [this is a bug with flutter doctor](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/27886).
Check yout flutter SDK version first,the latest version have fixed the issue.

Comment: Yeah I read the same one in github issue from flutter. You also need to check the path without any space. Thanks!

Comment: I already solved it on GitHub [issues #19359](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19359#issuecomment-518125343)